# Sentence Structure Nice to chatting with you is it correct

Tags: spoken-english

ladies and gentlemen!
I would like to ask about a sentence if it is correct or not.
Is Nice to chatting with you right? Does it have a grammatical error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is ungrammatical. It should be either

> It is nice chatting with you

or

> It is nice to chat with you